# How do I create a circular array like `Tab Layout` in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I am trying to create a circular array like `TabLayout` which has 5 tabs in it.

[image]

Currently, I am able to go *A <--> B <--> C <--> D <--> E.*
I want it to be infinite and after E, A should come again, like 
*...A <--> B <--> C <--> D <--> E <--> A <--> B <--> C <--> D <--> E ....*

How can I create this or find a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

A circular array represents a queue or FIFO structure that allows the head to chase around to meet the back. Please see The Wikipedia diagrams for better realisation.

The array indexes wrap around to form a circle. The next slot index is calculated by the mod(%) operator,

nextIndex := (lastIndex + 1) MOD arrayLength where both are integers

See [Circular buffer - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer)
Also [this](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Echeung/Courses/171/Syllabus/8-List/array-queue2.html)

Comment: Yes, I know how a circular array works. Is there any way to replicate it in TabLayout?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use a library [here is one](https://github.com/nshmura/RecyclerTabLayout) .. it implements the `TabLayout` behavior using a `RecyclerView`

[image]